problem with conect laravel 10 and dynamoDB
I created a laravel 10 project with a version of logging through the 'php artisan ui react' command. However, now I need to configure it with dynamoDB and I get this error 'Undefined array key “database”'.
I have set up env. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= AWS_DEFAULT_REGION= AWS_DYNAMODB_TABLE=users.
config/database.php I also set the ' '
'connections' => [
    'dynamodb' => [
        'driver' => 'dynamodb',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    ]
] 


How about giving it, what it demands?
'dynamodb' => [
    'driver'   => 'dynamodb',
    'key'      => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret'   => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region'   => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'database' => 'insert name here'
]

Else the server won't know which database shall be connected.

Right now I have this error 'Unsupported driver [dynamodb].'
